# Why sqlite return null for count(*) with group by query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

If I do simple query, for:

```sql
select count(*) from emails
where id <= 0
```

It returns one row of zeros.

However, if I group by the query, for:

```
select count(*) from emails
where id <= 0
group by emails.id
```

It returns no rows.

Why then behave differently and how to modify the second query to achieve the same behavior of the first one?

The command line ouputs:

```
sqlite> select count(*) from emails where id <= 0;
0
sqlite> select count(*) from emails where id <= 0 group by emails.id;
sqlite>
```

Comment: It doesn't make much sense for `id` to appear in both the `GROUP BY` and `WHERE` clauses.  Can you add some sample input and output data to your question?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve, do you ever expect id to be less than 0 for instance?

Comment: In your table you don't have any rows with `id <= 0`. So group by returns nothing. What is th eproblem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first query is an aggregation query with no `group by`:

```
select count(*)
from emails
where id <= 0;
```

Such a query is *always* guaranteed to return exactly one row.  The entire set of rows is treated as a single group, even when the table is empty or all rows are filtered out.  When this happens `COUNT()` returns `0`.  Most other aggregation functions (perhaps all of them) return `NULL`.  `COUNT()` never returns `NULL`.

Your second query:

```
select count(*)
from emails
where id <= 0
group by emails.id;
```

is an aggregation query *with* a `GROUP BY`.  Such a query returns one row for each set of values described by the `GROUP BY` keys.  In this case, there are no groups because all rows are filtered out.  Hence, this returns no rows at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(case when id <= 0 then 1 end) as cnt
from emails;
```

The problem with the `WHERE` clause is that should no record at all have `id <= 0`, there would be nothing in the result set.

Comment: *cnt* - Ooof. Dangerous territory

Answer (score 0):

This is because no rows exists with `id<=0` so it's exactly 0 rows in a table matching `id<=0` and no rows to show when trying to `group by id`.